# Calc direction vector based on destination vector and distance from enemy in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, vector

I'm working on a zombie game in AS3 where I want a character to be able to move away from a zombie depending upon how close the zombie is. The character also has a destination that it's trying to get too on the screen.

Ok so I have 2 vectors, one pointing to my destination, and one pointing to the zombie which I then invert to get my "away" vector. I then turn the distance between my character and the zombie into a value between 0 and 1. And then I'm stuck on how to get a resultant vector for my character. How would I use my 0-1 value to calculate how much of the away vector is used and how much of the original destination vector is still left if that makes sense? to end up with 1 direction vector to move my character? So if the zombie is right where my character is, then my direction vector = away vector, and if I'm far away from the zombie than my direction vector = destination vector, but how do I calculate the in-between?

Ideally need the answer in AS3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the vectors together, after scaling them.

```
 DestinationVector.scale(1-awayFactor)
 AwayVector.scale(awayFactor)

 CharacterDirection = DestinationVector + AwayVector
```

Where `awayFactor` is your 0-1 value.

Sorry, I don't know AS3, so I can't write it in that language.

If it's just `x` and `y` vectors this is the same as:

```
DestVec.x *= (1-awayFactor)
DestVec.y *= (1-awayFactor)

AwayVec.x *= awayFactor
AwayVec.y *= awayFactor

CharVec.x = DestVec.x + AwayVec.x
CharVec.y = DestVec.y + AwayVec.y
```

Comment: You can find the AS3 specific stuff [here](http://www.playchilla.com/vector-2d-for-as3)

Answer (score 1):

I would try ordinary [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation). If your destination vector is D (dx, dy, dz) and away vector is A (ax, ay, az), and your 0-1 value is V, then final vector F would be:

```
F = V * A + (1 - V) * D = (V * ax + (1 - V) * dx, ....)
```

If V is 1 (as in your example), you will get `F = 1 * A + (1 - 1) * D = A`, just as in your example.

But you should be careful with 0-1 value (if it isn't in range 0-1, then don't use interpolation) and also with vector normalization (I don't know, if you are using normalized vectors or not).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, ideally I need that in AS3 :) my vectors are just simple, x, y vectors, no z value.

Comment: @Phil It's just a simple formula using vectors. Write it yourself in AS3.

Comment: @Jonathan I understand AS3, not mathematical notation, but hey thanks for your really positive comment anyway.

Comment: @Phil It's only basic algebra, otherwise I wouldn't have said anything.